# Interface typecasting not working

Tags: go, interface, glide-golang

```
func GetResult (service interface{}) {
   switch v := service.(type) {
     case services.Account:
       service = service.(services.Account)
     default:
       service = service.(Mock_Account)
    }
   res, err := service.GetAccount()
 }
```

It says service is type of interface doesn't have any method. There is typecasting is not working any Idea how to call GetAccount method?

Comment: Go is statically typed so you can't change the type of `service`, and there is no type casting in go. If you only want to call `GetAccount`, why not accept an interface that only has that method?

Answer (score 3):

To annotate your code sample:

```
func GetResult (service interface{}) {
    // service is of type interface{}
    switch v := service.(type) {
    case services.Account:
        // This does nothing: it assigns the existing value back into service, which is still of type interface{}
        // v exists in scope and is of type services.Account, but it's unused.
        service = service.(services.Account)
    default:
        // Ditto
        service = service.(Mock_Account)
    }
    // service is still of type interface{}, which defines no methods
    res, err := service.GetAccount()
}
```

As you can see, the variable `service` here is *always* of type `interface{}`. A variable's type cannot change: Go is *static typed*. However, if you just want to call a method `GetAccount` on whatever type you get passed in, this can be done without the type assertions and with full type safety by declaring an interface:

```
type AccountGetter interface {
    GetAccount() (res ResultType, err error)
}

func GetResult(service AccountGetter) {
    res,err := service.GetAccount()
}
```

You can then call `GetResult` and pass a `services.Account` or a `Mock_Account` or any type that implements a `GetAccount` method with the appropriate signature.